# Singleton design pattern and asynchrounous method with EF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, uml

I have a wpf application, in which I used EF as an ORM.

I have many methods which called asynchrounously :

```
  public Task<double> GetSelectedOGCAvance2(int reference)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                DataEntities _db = new DataEntities();
                _db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                using (_db)
                {
                    var dpcs = _db.ass_dpc_ogc.Where(x => x.ass_dpc_id_fk == reference).ToList();
                    return (Double)dpcs[0].ass_dpc_ogc_avance2.Value;
                }
            });
        }
```

the method above is an example, all the methods used are similar to it.

I'd like to implement the `Singleton Pattern` to the **DbContext** ( _db) instead of creating and disposed it in each method.

I'd like to know if it is a good idea or not? if another way which  can improve the code exists, I'm open to suggestions

Comment: It is not a good idea to reuse your dbcontext over multiple threads. It is probably not thread safe and how can you start transactions etc... http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Feb/05/Linq-to-SQL-DataContext-Lifetime-Management

Comment: Any idea to improve this approach, i mean how can I make DbContext  thread safe

Comment: No, you should not even think about it. It is designed to have a short life time and is cheap to create/delete. It handles all the expensive stuff like connections (pooling) etc...

Comment: @peer but in my case when I used couple of asynchrounous method and each one takes a lot of time to be executed, I think this will generate a problem in the future if I added some other methods

Comment: The time is not in creating and deleting the db context, but in the db query. If the query is less expensive than the creating the dbcontext there is no point in doing it async. If your logic/db queries are so expensive it is probably better is finding a way to optimize them instead of looking to micro optimization which probably leads to faulty or undesired results under load.

Comment: @peer is correct. you shouldn't be using DBContexts like this (singleton). it is a simple use and throw away concept. you will also have issues with concurrency and threading issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Singleton Pattern is used to deny more than one instance to be created. *As a tolerated disadvantage* of this pattern, it creates a global variable. That's the price you pay for it's use.

You seem to be one of those people who want a global variable, have read that global variables are "bad" (tm) and now they found the singleton pattern and although they do not need it's advantages, they will happily pay it's price because now you have an excuse to have a global variable: *But it's a pattern!*

Stop that. Patterns are not good on their own. They are tools to fix problems. You don't have a problem, so don't fix it by applying a random tool!

Find your problem and only *then* look for a pattern. Hint: in 99%, Singleton will not be a good solution to your problem. Even if it seems that way, I guarantee you that dependency injection with a variable of "singleton" lifetime will be a lot better.

In your case, a single variable passed to all functions might be enough.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @nvoigt the Singleton is rarely a good idea, you are better off using an IoC to control the lifetime of your objects.

However if you wanted to write one, a good guide is Jon Skeet's [blog on singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx). A generic version of his sixth version might look like this:

```
public class Foo {}

public sealed class Singleton<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private static readonly Lazy<T> lazy = new Lazy<T>(() => new T());

    public static T Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private Singleton()
    {
    }
}

void Main()
{
    Foo foo1 = Singleton<Foo>.Instance;
    Foo foo2 = Singleton<Foo>.Instance;

    if(foo1 == foo2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foos are equal");
    }   
}
```

I haven't used `SimpleIoc` before but according to the [documentation](http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/WP8/html/d989c4c0-3070-bd7d-322e-8c8fed580abf.htm) you should be able to register a singleton instance like this:

```
var container = new GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc.SimpleIoc();

var foo = new Foo();
container.Register<Foo>(() => foo);

var foo1 = container.GetInstance<Foo>();
var foo2 = container.GetInstance<Foo>();

if(foo1 == foo2 && foo1 == foo)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Foos are equal");
}
```

Comment: How can I use the IoC (in my case it the SimpleIoC de MVVM Light) to control the lifetime of DBContexts ?